# IF EXISTS (SELECT 1...) vs IF EXITS (SELECT TOP 1 1...)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

This is a purely academic question.  Are these 2 statements effectively identical?

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM Table1)
 SELECT 1
ELSE
 SELECT 0
```

Versus

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table1)
 SELECT 1
ELSE
 SELECT 0
```

Comment: For modern query optimizer yes and probably they always were.

Comment: I didn't even think about the fact that queries go through an optimizer before being run.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you view the execution plan for these queries you can see that they are identical.  Good coding practices would ask that you leave out the "TOP 1" but they should run identical either way.

[image]

Comment: I agree it doesn't matter, but I wonder where this opinion comes from: "Good coding practices would ask that you leave out the 'TOP 1'"? I ask because when troubleshooting a query, sometimes I find myself manually running the select inside of an IF EXISTS to see what it finds, and on large tables it's nicer when it's "TOP 1 1" instead of "1" so don't have to temporarily edit it.