# Insert into linked server, if exist update

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to send data between two linked servers.

The INSERT INTO work perfectly, but I need to check if in the already inserted rows, it's present the same value of 2 specific columns, and if they already exists, I have to update them

Is there a way to do this?

This is my current code:

```
INSERT INTO [REMOTEPC\SQL].[REMOTEDB].[dbo].REMOTETABLE (COLUMREM1, COLUMREM2, COLUMREM3, COLUMREM4, COLUMREM5, COLUMREM6, COLUMREM7)
    SELECT COLUMLOC1, COLUMLOC2, COLUMLOC3, COLUMLOC4, COLUMLOC5, COLUMLOC6, COLUMLOC7 
    FROM LOCDB.dbo.LOCALTABLE
```

If `COLUMREM1` and `COLUMREM2` data already exists (they are a date and hour data, so it always unique), I have to update (or even skip is fine) the data present, if not I need to insert a new row.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server IF EXISTS THEN 1 ELSE 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41015307/sql-server-if-exists-then-1-else-2)

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [REMOTEPC\SQL].[REMOTEDB].[dbo].REMOTETABLE
    WHERE COLUMREM1 = @COLUMLOC1 AND COLUMREM2 = @COLUMLOC2
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE [REMOTEPC\SQL].[REMOTEDB].[dbo].REMOTETABLE
    SET COLUMREM3 = @COLUMLOC3,
        COLUMREM4 = @COLUMLOC4,
        COLUMREM5 = @COLUMLOC5,
        COLUMREM6 = @COLUMLOC6,
        COLUMREM7 = @COLUMLOC7
    WHERE COLUMREM1 = @COLUMLOC1 AND COLUMREM2 = @COLUMLOC2
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO [REMOTEPC\SQL].[REMOTEDB].[dbo].REMOTETABLE (COLUMREM1, COLUMREM2, COLUMREM3, COLUMREM4, COLUMREM5, COLUMREM6, COLUMREM7)
    VALUES (@COLUMLOC1, @COLUMLOC2, @COLUMLOC3, @COLUMLOC4, @COLUMLOC5, @COLUMLOC6, @COLUMLOC7)
END
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply but the MERGE function doesn't work with a remote table as TARGET, it can only be the SOURCE